# How to fix [terms] query does not support [query] within lookup element in elasticsearch repository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I want to find list of products by name. The query should be like this: `select * from product where name like '%{name}%'`

below is the elasticsearch query that I use:

```
@Query("{\"bool\" : {\"must\" : {\"terms\" : {\"name\" : {\"query\" : \"?*\",\"analyze_wildcard\" : true}}}}}")
    List<WarehouseProductDTO> findByName(String name);
```

When I run the project, it says [terms] query does not support [query] within lookup element

Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the [`query_string` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) instead of `terms`

```
@Query("{\"bool\" : {\"must\" : {\"query_string\" : {\"default_field\": \"name\", \"query\" : \"?*\",\"analyze_wildcard\" : true}}}}")
List<WarehouseProductDTO> findByName(String name);
```

Comment: It works! Thank you once again Val. Do you have any resource that I can use as a guide? I was using this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/elasticsearch.repositories.html but nothing works

Comment: It's probably not the right version. check here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out.

Comment: I just notice that your query actually give all the records instead of giving record according to the wildcard